# How to add wc booking to listify theme and user can add his own pricing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-bookings

I am using listify theme.I want my user can add his pricing also.Please see the demo link 
https://listify-demos.astoundify.com/rentals/listing/shared-south-beach-loft/

They added book now and calendar.How can a user can add his own price and integrate the calendar and hours ?

Comment: This one not place for better answer go to plugin provider site. Now this plugin in not exits this functionality (As per my used)

Comment: I have done it myself.Thanks for your reply

Comment: can you given us this suggestion how to fix ? customization or provide options